# Angular Routing Invalid URL Segment

Tags: routes, angular-routing, angular14

In my main Routing File

```
        RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: '', component: AppMainComponent,
            children: [
                {path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
                {
                    path: 'participants',
                    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/participants/participants.module').then(m => m.ParticipantsModule),
                    data: {breadcrumb: 'Participants'}
                }
            ]
        },
        {path: 'error', component: AppErrorComponent},
        {path: 'accessdenied', component: AppAccessdeniedComponent},
        // {path: 'notfound', component: AppNotfoundComponent},
        {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
        // {path: '**', redirectTo: '/notfound'},
    ], {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})
],
```

In my Child Module Routing

```
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {path: '', component: ParticipantsComponent},
        {path: 'participant/:id', component: ParticipantComponent},
    ])
],
```

in my child component i tried to navigate to another component but it says `URL Segment: 'participant;id=1001'`

```
this.router.navigate(['participant', {id: data.id}]);
```

What i have done wrong in here. I tried it it even by removing the params also but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `this.router.navigate` as shown above, you treat the `id` as a query-param even though it's just a normal route-param. I think you can pass an array of route-segments in order to fix this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/participants', 'participant', data.id]);
```

**Please note:**

The `/` at the beginning of the route is only needed if your route is a root-level route.

Comment: ```this.router.navigate(['/participants/participant', data.id])``` this works

Answer (score 0):

this.router.navigate(['/participants/participant', data.id]);

Comment: In my own answer actually forgot to add the `/participants` part. Could you please make sure if both suggestions in my updated answer work as well? It could be helpful for other users. I think good practise would be to either pass an array with single segments or pass a string containing the entire route. Your 'solution' is a mix of both of them. This of course works but it's not really ideal since it implies that `'/participants/participant'` must be one string, even though I'm almost sure this is not the case